# Create Thumbnail from url using asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, screenshot, thumbnails

Can any one help me on how to create a thumbnail from a url.

when the user saves a link, i want to show the screenshot of the web page as a thumbnail

i am using asp.net 2.0

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this yourself, you can use the Winforms WebBrowser control in an ASP.NET application, with a few caveats:

- It needs to run in a single threaded apartment thread
- It might not work on all pages, such as pages which require Javascript or Flash interaction

Here are a few links to some walkthroughs:

- [Build A Self-Caching ASP.NET Web Site Thumbnail Control](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx)
- [How To Get Web Site Thumbnail Image In ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Get-Web-Site-Thumbnail-Image.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using a webservice like [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/) or [WebShotsPro](http://www.webshotspro.com/).
[alt text http://beta.thumbalizr.com/app/thumbs/?src=/thumbs/onl/source/78/78f5e5a94c19c2999b1dc6eec3a2f2bf.png&w=640&q=0&enc=](http://beta.thumbalizr.com/app/thumbs/?src=/thumbs/onl/source/78/78f5e5a94c19c2999b1dc6eec3a2f2bf.png&w=640&q=0&enc=)

Comment: Thank's for the input. We can't user third party services as our company doesn't allow it.